# How does Kmail store offline IMAP

Tags: email, imap, kmail

I use KMail, and I have mail from Local Folders and an IMAP account. For the IMAP account, I have **Download all messages for offline use** enabled. My understanding is the offline IMAP messages are stored in `~/.local/share/akonadi`.

I want to back up the offline IMAP messages in case my email provider has a problem. I know that Akonadi provides a database for KDE applications, but I don't want to deal with Akonadi just to back up my messages. (I know I could backup `~/.local/share/akonadi`, but I'd prefer a simpler solution.)

Does `~/.local/share/akonadi/file_db_data/` contain all the messages as text files in the numbered subdirectories?